# Calculate the power of any exponent (negative or positive)

Tags: java, recursion

I want to calculate the result, given any exponent (negative or positive) and a base of type integer. I am using recursion:

```
public static double hoch(double basis, int exponent) {
    if (exponent > 0) {
        return (basis * hoch(basis, exponent - 1));
    } else if (exponent < 0) {
        return ((1 / (basis * hoch(basis, exponent + 1))));
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

If exponent is negative 1.0 is returned but that is wrong. For e.g. hoch(2,-2) it should be 0.25. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 }else if(exponent < 0){
         return ((1/(basis*hoch(basis, exponent+1))))
```

should be

```
 }else if(exponent < 0){
        return (1/hoch(basis, -exponent));
```

Comment: what's the -exponent? why not use exponent-1

Comment: if you don't increment/decrement the exponent, you'll end up with a stack overflow exception

Comment: oh I mean why not use exponent+1? whats the meaning of -exponent?

Comment: @Andreas_D, no, that's not the case. Since the next recursive call will be with a postive exponent, it will be decremented then. n**(-m) is the same as 1/(n**m)

Comment: @ArtWorkAD, n**(-m) is the same as 1/(n**m)

Comment: @Paul - ah got it, you change the sign once and the rest of the recursion continues in the `exponent>1` branch.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static double hoch(double basis, int exponent){
    if(exponent > 0){
        return basis*hoch(basis, exponent-1);
    }else if(exponent < 0){
        return hoch(basis, exponent+1)/basis;
    }else{
        return 1;
    }
}
```

although the more efficient (recursive) solution is

```
public static double hoch(double basis, int exponent){
    if(exponent == 0)
        return 1;
    else{
        double r = hoch(basis, exponent/2);
        if(exponent % 2 < 0)
            return r * r / basis;
        else if(exponent % 2 > 0)
            return r * r * basis;
        else
            return r * r;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your parentheses are the wrong way around. You want to be multiplying by the result of the recursive call, not dividing by it; and you want the thing you multiply by to be `1/basis` (which "peels off" one negative exponent).

Answer (score 1):

With hoch(2,-2) you actually calculate

```
     1 / (-2 * (1 / (-1 * (1 / 1)))
<=>  1 / (-2 * (1 / (-1))
<=>  1 / (-2 * -1)
<=>  1/2
```

Answer (score 0):

Working code for raising BASE to a pos or neg BASE:

```
FUNC Raise_To_Power

LPARAMETERS pnBase, pnPow

DO CASE

  CASE pnPow = 0
    RETURN 1  
  CASE pnPow > 0
    RETURN pnBase * Raise_To_Power(pnBase, pnPow-1)  
  CASE pnPow < 0
    RETURN 1 / (pnBase * Raise_To_Power(pnBase, -(pnPow+1)))

ENDCASE

ENDFUNC
```